# Threading in C#: How to keep loop-index thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

In the following example, it seems that the index `i` of the for-loop is modified independently by each thread leading to strange values of `i` (multiples, even values larger than `System.Environment.ProcessorCount-1`) in `DoWork_Threaded()`

How are multithreaded loops properly done in C# ?

```
// Prepare all threads
Thread[] threads = new Thread[System.Environment.ProcessorCount];

// Start all threads
for (int i = 0; i < System.Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
{
   threads[i] = new Thread(() => DoWork_Threaded(i));
   threads[i].Start();
}

// Wait for completion of all threads
for (int i = 0; i < System.Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
{
   threads[i].Join();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how would this help with the index i ? PS: It is also not working.

Comment: try to copy the value inside the loop `int a = i;` then  `DoWork_Threaded(a);`

Comment: For some explanation why your code behaves like it does you can read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/. It's also completely unrelated to threading. Any closure over loop variables can cause the behaviour you described.

Comment: @Dirk: Though the cause of the problem is unrelated to threading, accessing the closure from multiple threads makes the problem far worse, since the observed value of the variable becomes undetermined.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a [**ThreadPool**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/threadpool)? It seems you want to implement something similar to this. And for the index part, you might want to read [**this**](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Passing_Data_to_a_Thread) to understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, rather than rolling your own thread scheduling service, why not use the task parallel library? It already has logic that determines the number of processors to schedule threads onto.

To answer your actual question, you are *closing over a loop variable*.  See my article on why that is wrong:

https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/

In short: `i` is a *variable* and variables *change*. When your lambda executes, it executes with the *current* value of `i`, not the value it used to have when the delegate was created.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the TPL which is pretty nice. However, in my case we have many (million, think image pixels) elements that are processed manually distributed over all cores. Although doesing this seems error-prone compared to just using Parallel.For, it also is much faster. I do not know how Parallel.For distributes the work but I assume this is due to the overhead of creating much more threads...maybe even for every element?

Comment: Is there a way to tell the TPL in such case (millions of elements in Parallel.For loop) to (in the exemplary case of 4 cores) use core 1 for the first quarter, core 2 for the second quarter and so on?

Comment: @ares_games: This is a question-and-answer site; that sounds like a good question to post, either here or even better, on the games site.

Answer (score 4):

Using local variables with anonymous methods and threads might be tricky. You need to copy the value that is being used by the anonymous method as it is changing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < System.Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
{
     int a = i;
     threads[i] = new Thread(() => DoWork_Threaded(a));
     threads[i].Start();
}
```

**This makes the output rational on my machine.**