# Do anonymous methods passed to actions obtain data by value or reference?

Tags: c#, anonymous-methods

I am creating an anonymous method and passing it into an action to be invoked later on. I would like to pass some numeric data (`int`) into my anonymous method. In order to pass the data by value, am I required to create copies? Or, will the data be passed by value?

Here is what I think the implementation would look like, if I had to create copies:

```
private void CreateAction()
{
    int bus = 4;
    CustomObject[] data = new object[16];
    int length = 1500;

    this.doWorkLater = new Action(() =>
    {
        var busCopy = bus;
        var dataCopy = data;
        var lengthCopy = length;

        this.WorkMethod(busCopy, dataCopy, lengthCopy);
    });
}
```

Is this (*the above code*) necessary in order  to get `length` and `bus` by value?

In this case, will `CustomObject[] data` (*some class I have created*) be passed by reference or by value?

Comment: Variables are captured, not values. Since these variables are local to the method you don't need to copy them since nothing else can modify them.

Comment: A good read on this note is [Eric Lippert - Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you pass is not a By-Value Copy.

If you're not going to modify the values before executing the action, then you don't need to worry about how you pass the values. But no they are no passed by value. Even if you return the action and `Invoke` it from another method. the values are persisted in a class generated by the compiler. No need to worry about that

If you expect the data to change before executing the action then you're doing it wrong. The approach you're using (Copy a Value-Type to a local variable) should be done outside the action and not inside of it. As for the reference type (Array) even if you copy it to a local variable, the reference it copied so any change in the copy local variable is reflected.

```
private void CreateAction()
{
    int bus = 4;
    CustomObject[] data = new object[16];
    int length = 1500;

    var busCopy = bus; // a copy of bus
    var dataCopy = data; // reference copy
    var lengthCopy = length; // a copy of length

    this.doWorkLater = new Action(() =>
    {
        this.WorkMethod(busCopy, dataCopy, lengthCopy);
    });

    bus = 10; // No effect on the action
    length = 1700; // No effect on the action

    this.doWorkLater();
}
```

This looks pointless, but you may sometimes need to copy a local variable to another local variable before passing it to an anonymous method. Check this [Valid Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38309084/3185569) that fixes a reported unexpected behavior !

Comment: Seems ridiculous to copy the objects I just created... Doesn't it? I think there's something wrong with this.

Comment: @StevieV No it is not ridiculous. There are valid cases where you need to do that. If you want to pass it by value to an anonymous method. Check this valid example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38309084/3185569

Comment: It's not like I'm needing to close inside of a loop. So what you're doing doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @StevieV If you're not going to mutate the variables after closing over them, there's no need for the copy.  If the method is going to mutate them after they're being closed over, and the anonymous method doesn't want to observe those changes, *then* you need to create a second variable to close over.

Comment: Ok, in that guy's example he is modifying the value after he passes it. I am not doing that.

Comment: So he is required to make a copy. Please reference *my* example and explain why you think I need to do this.

Comment: @StevieV So no need to create copy the values. Check the edited answer. But no the values are not passed By-Value. They are captured in a automatically generated static class by the compiler. But if the values are not going to change, why do you care if they are care to pass them by value in this particular example ?

Comment: @StevieV No need to worry. Even if you return the action and run it inside another method. the values are persisted in a static hidden class. No need to worry about that.

Comment: Yeah that was the biggest part of my concern, I kind of knew a little about how these anonymous methods worked already but was missing that concept.

Comment: @StevieV Glad to hear that this helped you understand that more :)

Comment: @user3185569 please make sure that when you say "in a static hidden" you mean exactly that (which is not true)... I suspect you did not want to use `static` there. Also `dataCopy = data; // this is useless` - not exactly true - same problem of modifying `data` itself (not content of array) still exists for reference types.

Answer (score 1):

Closures capture values observably by reference<sup>*</sup> - note that code you have does not solve issue for general case, also if whole point of `CreateAction` is create one single action it will work.

```
private void CreateAction()
{
    int bus = 4;

    this.doWorkLater = new Action(() =>
    {
        var busCopy = bus;

        this.WorkMethod(busCopy);
    });
    // if you change local `bus` before call to `doWorkLater` it will not work:
    bus = 42;
    doWorkLater(); // busCopy is 42. 
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> It actually collects all variables in a compiler created class and uses reference to it to access variables in a method and closure. Thus even value types look behave as if passed by reference.

Comment: Let's say I leave the method right after I create the closures and that `bus` never gets changed. Will I get some kind of error because `bus` no longer exists?

Comment: @StevieV Run the code and find out.  You already have it written.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to figure out what's going on.

If you start with this slightly simplified class:

```
public class Example
{
    private void CreateAction()
    {
        int bus = 4;
        object[] data = new object[16];
        int length = 1500;

        Action doWorkLater = () =>
        {
            var busCopy = bus;
            var dataCopy = data;
            var lengthCopy = length;

            this.WorkMethod(busCopy, dataCopy, lengthCopy);
        };

        doWorkLater.Invoke();
    }

    public void WorkMethod(int bus, object[] data, int length)
    {
    }
}
```

...then the compiler produces basically this:

```
public class Example
{
    private void CreateAction()
    {
        Example.GeneratedClass closure = new Example.GeneratedClass();
        closure.parent = this;
        closure.bus = 4;
        closure.data = new object[16];
        closure.length = 1500;

        // ISSUE: method pointer
        IntPtr method = __methodptr(closure.CreateAction);
        new Action((object)closure, method)();
    }

    public void WorkMethod(int bus, object[] data, int length)
    {
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class GeneratedClass
    {
        public int bus;
        public object[] data;
        public int length;
        public Example parent;

        internal void CreateAction()
        {
            this.parent.WorkMethod(this.bus, this.data, this.length);
        }
    }
}
```

The local variables trapped in the closure cease being local variables to the method and become public fields in the generate class.

Now everything that you know about C# and classes applies.